# How can I register custom data type in PascalScript?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, pascalscript

I can register custom function like this:

```
procedure TForm1.PSScript1ExecImport(Sender: TObject; se: TPSExec;
  x: TPSRuntimeClassImporter);
begin
  se.RegisterDelphiFunction(@MWrites, 'Writes', cdRegister);
end;
```

and custom class like this:

```
procedure TForm1.PSScript1ExecImport(Sender: TObject; se: TPSExec;
  x: TPSRuntimeClassImporter);
var CustomClass: TPSRuntimeClass;
begin
  CustomClass := x.Add(TPerson);
  CustomClass.RegisterMethod(@TPerson.setAge, 'setAge'); 
end;
```

.

```
type TCallback = procedure;
```

But how can I add TCallback to PascalScript?

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  TCallback = procedure;

  TPerson = class(TObject)
    procedure setAge(AValue: TCallback);
  end;  

procedure TForm1.PSScript1Compile(Sender: TPSScript);
var CustomClass: TPSCompileTimeClass;
begin
  CustomClass := Sender.Comp.AddClass(Sender.Comp.FindClass('TObject'), TPerson);
   Sender.Comp.AddTypeS('TCallback', 'procedure');
   Customclass.RegisterMethod('procedure setAge(AValue: TCallback)');   
end;
```